# Azure Cognitive Search

Tags: azure-cognitive-search, azure-cognitive-services

In Azure blob Storage account I have a file of 550 MB which is a TSV file (Tab is the delimited text). when I am trying to import data using portal in the Azure Congnitive search i am getting error as below

`Sampling data source
Error detecting index schema from data source: "Could not build a prototype index because datasource 'dcswiki' returned no data."`

The permission seems fine, but I am not sure is it a issue with the file itself or portal doesn't support import of 550 MB of file.

Comment: Hi Shobhit, I believe there's a bug on the azure portal on how it serializes the delimiter character. I'm assuming you set the parsing mode to "Delimited text" and the delimited character as "\t". The portal will serialize this into "\\t", which causes incorrect behavior. 

To get around this, you will have to rely on the rest API and specify your delimited character as "\t".

Comment: It seems this is not the case because the small version (having only 20 records) of the same file working fine. To me it seems something with the size.

Comment: What is the service tier for your search service? Limits for blob size vary across service tiers (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-limits-quotas-capacity#indexer-limits).

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug in the portal. The portal cognitive search pipeline works for Azure SQL Database data sources, just **not Cosmos DB or Blob storage** right now.

For more details, you could refer to this similar [issue](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/24491).

Comment: I checked that issue but from the comment it seems it was resolved. As I am able to index the small TSV files from portal